# Make string shorter. Cut it by the last word

Tags: php

How to make string shorter by cut it on the last word?

like example, allowed symbols are 10, and echo only these words which fits in this limit.

```
$string = 'Hello Hello John Doe'

// Limit 10. Expected result:
$string = 'Hello'

// Limit 12. Expected result:
$string = 'Hello Hello'
...
```

All I can find in manual is cutting string by symbols, not by words. There are some custom functions to do so, but maybe there are php command for this?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Been asked many times.

Comment: This is a really confusing question.  You say "cut it on the last word", and yet you're expecting the first word.  Then you say "allowed symbols are 10", which doesn't seem to have anything to do with what you said before.  Finally you say you want to "echo only these words".  So what do you actually want to do?

Comment: As @relentless said, you can make a substring. What is the problem?

Comment: `explode`, `preg_match`, and `preg_match_all` are other good functions to look at

Comment: it cuts symbols, but not words :(

Comment: just split the string and add the parts together while the size is smaller than target. Also -1 for "I have google too"

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu ha ha you're right. oops.

Comment: sorry guys, mad mood today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$str = "i have google too";
$strarr = explode(" ", $str);

$res = "";

foreach($strarr as $k) 
{
    if (strlen($res.$k)<10)
    {
        $res .= $k." ";
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    };
}

echo $res;
```

http://codepad.org/NP9t4IRi

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: update version to cope with word breaks better.

This shouldn't be too difficult. Truncate to the maximum length, then truncate to the last space. Add an adjustment for lengths that fall on the end of words

```
<?php
$str = "Hello Hello My name is Hal";
for ($i = 3; $i <30;$i++) {
echo "'".trunc($str,$i)."'\n";
}

function trunc($str, $len) {
$str.=' ';
$out = substr($str,0,$len+1);
$out = substr($out,0,strrpos($out,' '));
return trim($out); 
}
```

Here's a [codepad version](http://codepad.org/XOFu4MgB)

Comment: This only works if the last word was truncated. If it was not you loose a word.

Comment: @Gediminas Try it with `$len = 11` or `$len = 100` and you'll see the problem.

Comment: oh, yes. I can't see the last word

Answer (score 1):

Tried to edit Mike's answer, to fix the last word thing, but was not able to.

So here is his solution with the fix:

```
$str = "Hello Hello My name is Hal";
$len = 10;

if ( strlen( $str ) > $len )
{
    $out = substr($str,0,$len);
    if ( $str[$len] != ' ')
    {
        $out = substr($out,0,strrpos($out,' '));
    }
}

echo $out; // Hello
```